# Ruby On Rails : How to retrieve data from database on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form and while typing in the input field I need to get all the categories 
which contains that keyword from the categories table .

I have two controllers viz. Books and Categories.

The prime objective is to add a book and select a category.

I need to do this using ajax.

I have tried a lot. But none of them works.

I have included jquery and all needed scripts. But still its showing.

Anyone can help me with this?

JQUERY

```
$('#book_search').keyup(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"books/new",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: {keyword: '$("input[name'search']").val()},
                    success:function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                })
            })
```

HTML

```
<%= simple_form_for :book, url: books_path do |f| %>
                <p> <%= f.label :name %> <%= f.text_field :name %> </p>
                <p> <%= f.input :category, collection: @categories, prompt: "Select Category" %></p>
                <p> <%= f.label :search %> <%= f.text_field :search %> </p>
                <p> <%= f.submit %></p>
            <% end %>



class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @books = Book.all
        @categories = Category.all
    end
    def new
        @categories = Category.all
    end

    def create
        @book = Book.new(book_params)        
        @book.save
        redirect_to @book
    end

    def show
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        @categories = Category.all
    end

    def show_categories
        @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
        def book_params
            params.require(:book).permit(:name, :category)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of libraries that implement auto complete, including the 2 most popular, autocomplete and type-ahead.

However, obviously every library is extra overhead so if you want to implement it yourself, you certainly can.

Some things to consider:

1. The URL of the request -- given that in this case you don't care about hte books, and really just want a list of all potentially matching categories, best to call to a categories controller and place your code there accordingly.
2. You'll want to return a list so users can choose, but you don't need to pass that list to the controller, so a hidden field for the category_id is a good idea, this way you can ignore everything that strong params already filters out and just keep the good stuff.
3. jBuilder is your friend.  It lets you lay out JSON anyway you want without clouding your controllers.  In this case it's not strictly necessary, because all you need is a label field and an id field, but I'll throw it in for good measure.
4. Since you are using `@categories` in your standard controller call, I would be hesitant to use the same instance variable to return your search results, thus I named it differently.
5. The drop down box you have in your original example is unnecessary as far as I see it because an unordered list is just as good with less code.

Given that, you could do something like this in your view (form)

#### View

```
<div id="book_create">
    <%= simple_form_for :book, url: books_path do |f|  %>
        <%= f.input :name  %>
        <%= f.input :category_id, as: :hidden %>
        <%= f.input :category_search, as: :string, input_html: {class: "book_search"} , autocomplete: false %>
        <div id="cat_search"></div>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<style>
    #categories { width: 200px; max-height: 220px; overflow: scroll; box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.43); list-style: none; padding: 0; }
    #categories li:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: rgb(238, 247, 255); }
    #categories li { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```

Simple css included for good measure.

#### Javascript

```
$('.book_search').keyup(function(){
    var q = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/categories/search",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'keyword': q},
        success: function(result){
            $("#categories").remove();
            $("#cat_search").after('<ul id="categories"></ul>');
            render = true;
            $("#categories").on("click", "li", function(){
                $("#book_category_id").val($(this).data('id'));
                $(".book_search").val($(this).text());
                $("#categories").remove();
            });
            for(term in result){
                render = false;
                $("#categories").append("<li data-id="+result[term].id+">" + result[term].keyword + "</li>");
            }
        }
    })
});
```

There's really no rails magic in this JS, it's just straightforward jQuery.  You grab the users input and make a call to a url with the user input as the query, if the query is returned, remove any previous display list then build a display a list (ul) for the user with all the possible results.  Clicking on the result of your choice does 2 things, it a.) adds the id from the data attribute we injected  from the result set and b.) clears the input field the user typed in replacing it with the full name of their selected result.

#### Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    respond_to :json, :html
    def search
        @cat_search_results = Category.where("keyword LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{params[:keyword].downcase}%")
        respond_with(@cat_search_results, :include => :status)
    end
end
```

#### Jbuilder

```
#/categories/search.json.jbuilder
json.array!(@cat_search_results) do |category|
    json.extract! category, :id, :keyword
end
```

#### Routes

```
resources categories do
    collection do
        get :search
    end
end
```